# Hiding div with Javascript based on value of php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have a select box in my laravel blade:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div>
    <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
    <select id="filterText" class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" onchange="filterText()" >
      <option id="allitems" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" selected data-default value="" selected data-default>All Items</option>
      <option id="popular" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="" >Popularity</option>
      <option id="recent" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="">Recently Ordered </option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

And I want to use JS to show/hide my `.groupcontainer` div based on the value of a PHP variable. I have a function that creates PHP variables `$topsellers` and `$reorder`. So I want to map my option `popularity` to `$topsellers` and the option `Recently Ordered` to `$reorder`

I have some JS that I was playing with but I don't know how to do this properly, however, it gives an idea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#filterText').on('change', function () {
if (this.value == '') {
  $(".groupcontainer").show();
} else {
  $(".groupcontainer").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

But basically, I want to say :

> if value popularity is selected and `$topsellers == true`, show the groupcontainer div, and if value recently ordered is selected and `$reorder` is true, only show those groupcontainer divs.

I hope that makes sense. I feel like the pieces are there but I need help connecting them with logic and syntax.

UPDATE (new attempted solution):

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#filterText').on('change', function () {

var topsellers = "<?php echo $pgroups->topseller; ?>";
var reorder    = "<?php echo $pgroups->reorder; ?>";

 var currentVal = $(this).val();

 if (currentVal == 'popularity' && topsellers == "true" || currentVal == 'recently_ordered' && reorder == "true") {
   $(".groupcontainer").show();
 } else {
   $(".groupcontainer").hide();
 }
});
</script>
```

HTML/Select box:

```
    <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <div>
                                    <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
                                    <select id="filterText" class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" onchange="filterText()" >
                                        <option id="allitems" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" selected data-default value="" selected data-default>All Items</option>
                                      <option id="popular" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="popularity" >Popularity</option>
                                      <option id="recent" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="recently_ordered">Recently Ordered </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You would either need to write the HTML sections inside of a PHP conditional, or use JavaScript to call the PHP file with the selection information via AJAX.

Comment: Could you help me with that, possibly the PHP conditional? It's showing all products the way I want to now, but I would want to do something in my blade that would set the div as either having $topsellers/$reorder as true or false

Comment: The general way to go would be AJAX. Also, look into the jQuery.toggle() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add hidden inputs for those values like :

```
<input class="topsellers" value="{{$topsellers}}" />
<input class="reorder" value="{{$reorder}}" />
```

Or you could put the variables to the Js variables like :

```
var topsellers = "<?php echo $topsellers; ?>";
var reorder    = "<?php echo $reorder; ?>";
```

Then use those value in the condition in your JS code, something like :

```
$(function(){
    var topsellers = "<?php echo $topsellers; ?>";
    var reorder    = "<?php echo $reorder; ?>";

    $('#filterText').on('change', function() {
      var currentVal = $(this).val();

      if (currentVal == 'popularity' && topsellers == "1" || currentVal == 'recently_ordered' && reorder == "1") {
        $(".groupcontainer").show();
      } else {
        $(".groupcontainer").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes perfect since, but I'm getting no action from my select box. Do you mind to see my update to verify it loooks correct before I investigate further?

Comment: I think you should remove `onchange="filterText()"` first, then add a `console.log(topsellers)` just after the variables definition and let me know what's the output

Comment: It looks like I'm getting a lot of referenceError: $ is not define

Comment: Make sure the jQuery is included and check my update using the ready function.

Comment: Yes it is being included. I've tried with the update and it still doesn't have any action. I'm going to accept the answer though, and I may need to investigate the controller where the variables are created

Comment: Thanks so much, if you don't mind helping still I have an update. I've updated my code to show the proper variable syntax. I dumped my json data and I see the topsellers and recently ordered in the JSOn as either 1 or 0 so I know the values are loading

Comment: Okey try my update using `1` instead of `true` and you could debug using `console.log( topsellers == "1" )` to check if the condition will work fine.

Comment: Ok so I did that and it looks like the console just printed ```false``` one time. But the page shows many product groups and some have 0 or 1 set, so it's just referring to the first group

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP is a backend language you have to expose the variable in javascript context which is at the browser level.  To do so what you would end up doing is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var somePHPVariable = "<?php echo $SOMEVAR; ?>";
...
</script>
```

That now gives you the PHP variable at the javascript level so you can do operations on it just like you would with any other javascript variable.  Just keep in mind that PHP renders / computes before javascript does, so your php variables will always be set first.  The alternative to this would be to "ask php" via rest / ajax request what the value is and then continue calculation based on the result.